# JS: Window.location the value of a localstorage key

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage, window.location

I am trying to redirect users of value of a localstorage key but it doesn't seem to work.

Now this works:  `window.location = "http://google.com"`

but this doesnt: `window.location = localStorage.getItem('key1')`

The value of the key1 is http://google.com ...

Does it not work because localstorage doesn't take `://` as a string or something like it?

Thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked fine for me in firefox:

```
localStorage.setItem("key1", "http://google.com");  
window.location = localStorage.getItem('key1');
```

Most likely you have a mistake somewhere when you store.

Try doing

```
alert(localStorage.getItem('key1'));
```

to see what you actually store.

Comment: What browser were you using and what version? In firefox 7.0.1 I see http://google.com .